# How to define day is sunday and Normal day. using switch case by date?

Tags: php, javascript

I have an error in this code. Please help me solve it.

```
function holiday($today) {    

    $year = substr($today, 0, 4);     

    switch($today) {

      case $year.'-01-01':
          $holiday = 'New Year';
          break;

      case $today:
          $today11 = new DateTime($today);
          $R= $today11->format('l') . PHP_EOL;
          $Sunday='0';

          if($R == 0) {
              $holiday = 'Sunday';
          } else {
              $holiday = 'Normal Day';  
          }
      }

      return $holiday;
}

echo $tday= holiday($today);
```

Comment: -1 because "please fix this code" is not very helpful either to future visitors or to people answering. Include a better problem description: What happens? What doesn't happen? What errors do you get? *What are you trying to do?*

Comment: Do-my-homework-but-I-wont-pay-you type question.

Comment: @emil Vikstrom : i am trying for get today is Sunday ya normal day.

Comment: @jashwant:i don't know what are you saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:-

```
function holyday($today)
{
    $start_date = strtotime($today);


    if(date('z',$start_date) ==0)
    {
         return 'New Year';

    }else{

        if(date('l',$start_date) =='Sunday')
        {
             return 'Sunday';

        }else{

            return "Noraml Day";
        }
    }
}

echo holyday('2012-09-06');
```

Output = Noraml Day

```
echo holyday('2013-01-01');
```

Output = New year

Comment: what is error? Please explain.

Comment: no response return .how to get output for your code .my post code return output in this variable. echo $tday= holiday($today);

Comment: how to include special date in your code for example :2013-02-05 is bank holyday

Comment: You can include $spdate = date("Y-m-d"): echo holyday($spdate); and try it.

Comment: sorry for say. where include in this code please describe properly  .

Comment: use this function according to your requirement. add in your php file

Comment: how to use bank holiday and date which is in database table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using switch for this, please read up on how to use [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). The function below will work:

```
function holiday($today) {
    // z returns the number of the day in the year, 0 being first of January
    if(date("z", $today) == 0) {
         return "New Year";
    }

    // w returns the number of the day in the week 0-6 where 0 is Sunday
    if(date("w", $today) == 0) {
         return "Sunday";
    }

    return "Normal Day";
}

$today = date();
echo holiday($today);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working implementation of your holiday() function:

```
function holiday($today) {    

$date = strtotime($today);     

//check if Sunday
if (date('l', $date) == 'Sunday') {
    return 'Sunday';
}

//check if New Year
if ((date('j', $date) == 1) && (date('n', $date) == 1)) {
    return 'New Year';
}

//else, just return Normal Day
return 'Normal Day';

}

//$today is in YYY/MM/DD format
echo $tday = holiday($today);
```

Also, PHP's `date` reference can come in handy in this case: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php